# Get content:// Uri of Current Ringtone

Tags: android, audio, uri, ringtone, android-contentresolver

I am trying to get the content uri (`content://media/external/...`) of the current ringtone.

I get the current device ringtone like this:

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);`
```

However, calling `uri.getPath()` returns `external/audio/media/50`. It is missing `content://media/` in front of it. I have thought about manually pasting it to the beginning but that just seems wrong.

How do I properly get the `content://` uri of the current ringtone?

Thank you!

Comment: you dont need to get path, use uri directly

Comment: But I need to save reference to the current ringtone so I can set it later. I am saving it in a database. So far I have been saving content:// paths, is there another way?

Comment: doesnt uri already have the content:// part?

Comment: Like I said above calling getPath() returns the path without the content:// appendage. Is it as simple as manually adding that to the beginning? Just seems wrong.

Comment: AH and it was so simple. Thank you, that was what I was missing. If you want to officially answer this question I will certainly vote you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `uri.toString()` instead of `uri.getPath()`.

`uri.getPath()` is usually used by ContentProvider when it wants to decode the uri and create query.